# How to conditionally print "There is no value if there is no value for output"

Tags: python

How can I modify this code to do the following: If there is a value for the output, then it should print "There is no armstrong number b/w the numbers"

```
def armstrong(num1, num2):
for x in range(num1, num2 + 1):
    temp = x
    new_val = 0
    while x > 0:
        val = x % 10
        x //= 10
        new_val = new_val + val**3
  
    if new_val == temp:
        print(new_val)
```

Comment: what is the problem you seem to have with this?

Answer (score 0):

First I would break it down into 2 separate functions.

The first function returns whether or not a number N is an armstrong number, and the second one prints all armstrong numbers in a given range OR a message that no armstrong number was found:

```
def is_armstrong(n):
    return n == sum(int(c)**3 for c in str(n))

def print_armstrong(begin, end):
    armstrong_found = False
    
    for n in range(begin, end+1):
        if is_armstrong(n):
            print(n)
            armstrong_found = True
    
    if not armstrong_found:
        print('There is no armstrong number in the given range')
```

Comment: Ya, thanks for the solution and I tried too for the solution. First I made a list and after every iteration I appended it to the list then after the iteration is done and if the list is empty, it would print the same and it worked..